# "spread operator" to iterate subset of JSON

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I'm parsing a JSON which does not start with [] brackets. Instead you see the following:

```
{
  "result":{
    "heroes":[
      {
        "name":"npc_dota_hero_antimage",
        "id":1,
        "localized_name":"Anti-Mage"
      },
      ...
    ]
  }
}
```

There are a total of 115 items.

When trying to use ES6's spread operator `...` like so,

```
const endpoint = './heroes.json'
let heroes = []
fetch(endpoint)
  .then(blob => blob.json())
  .then(data => heroes.push(...data))
```

I will not be able to iterate over the JSON due to `result` and `heroes` shielding the objects.

Is there a way to use the spread operator on the above JSON structure?
If so, how then would i console log to give me the first item's name of `Anti-Mage` ?

Comment: Did you try `...data.result.heroes`?

Comment: @zero298 That did it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Post how you are using `heroes`.  Is it outside of the `then()`?  If so, you are trying to synchronously access an asynchronous resource.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the spread on the property that **is** an array:

```
fetch('./heroes.json')
  .then(blob => blob.json())
  .then(data => ...data.result.heroes)
  .then(heroes => console.log(heroes));
```

Consider this:

```js
const nested = {
  foo: {
    bar: {
      fizz: {
        buzz: ["hello", "world"]
      }
    }
  }
};

function test(first, second) {
  console.log(`first: ${first} | second: ${second}`);
}
test(...nested.foo.bar.fizz.buzz);
```

Comment: @ zero298 Since I'm fetching the JSON from another site I can't really make a const/variable out of it. Adding the `.then(heroes => console.log(heroes));` however works to be able to reach it. Why ? How come I can't reach the value with an outside-console.log, but pairing it with `.then` within the function works ?

Comment: @Helle You need to read this question: [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23667086/691711).

Comment: Makes  a lot of sense, thank you for that. I have trouble implementing that in this simple `fetch`. Can you point me in the right direction?